# Modal image gallery slider fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a gallery that contains 6-9 images, I'm trying to create something like that =>
[W3schools Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp)
But without writing the code twice as in the example and without the `column` at the bottom of the gallery (without showing the other images when fullscreen - only the number of the image and the Previous/Next buttons)
The whole point is to create the Modal when the `IMG` is clicked, and delete it when the Modal is closed (not to toggle between `display: none;` and `display: block;`)

Anyone can help please?
Thank you :)!

```
    <div class="category-gallery">
        <div id="Gallery1" class="gallery-box">
            <div class="gallery-img-container">
                <div class="gallery-img-box">
                    <img src="card-image.png" class="gallery-img">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img-container">
                <div class="gallery-img-box">
                    <img src="card-image.png" class="gallery-img">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img-container">
                <div class="gallery-img-box">
                    <img src="card-image.png" class="gallery-img">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img-container">
                <div class="gallery-img-box">
                    <img src="card-image.png" class="gallery-img">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.category-gallery { 
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery-img-container {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    min-height: 180px;
    flex: 0 0 30.333333%;
    max-width: 30.333333%;
    margin: 30px 1.5% 30px 1.5%;
}

.gallery-img-box {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-img-box span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.gallery-img-box:hover > span {
    opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .gallery-img-box {
        height: 200px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
    .gallery-img-container {
        flex: 0 0 40%;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 30px 5% 50px 5%;
        
    }
}

@media (max-width:768px){ 
    .gallery-img-container {
        flex: 0 0 70%;
        max-width: 70%;
        margin: 30px 15% 30px 15%;
    }
}
                            
@media (max-width:576px){
    .gallery-img-container {
        flex: 0 0 80%;
        max-width: 80%;
        margin: 30px 10% 30px 10%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `column` from HTML. You can use the same example just removing unnecessary content (in your case `column`)

Comment: But the code is written twice in the example! that means I have to copy paste the `img` tag every time I add an image.

Comment: Oh, do you mean that you need to put the images twice but you don't want that - in modal and in original showcase (`myModal` and `row`)?

Comment: Yes! DRY coding... I don't want to copy-paste the `img` tag twice in the page content and in the modal.. My goal = When the `img` is clicked it'll open in fullscreen and have the ability to click pre/next to see the other images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you looking to change this to be about this one:

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.column img');
  var captionText = document.getElementsByClassName("numbertext")[0];
  var modalImg = document.querySelector('.modal-content img');
  n %= slides.length;
  modalImg.src = slides[n].src;
  captionText.innerHTML = n + 1 + ' / ' + slides.length;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(0)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

***--- VERSION 2 ---***

According to the requirements in the comments below, here is an updated example, where the modal built dynamically:

```js
var modal = initModal();

function initModal() {
  return render({
    tag: 'div',
    id: 'myModal',
    className: 'modal',
    children: [
      {
        tag: 'span',
        className: 'close cursor',
        onclick: closeModal,
        innerHTML: '&times;'
      },
      {
        tag: 'div',
        className: 'modal-content',
        children: [
          {
            tag: 'div',
            className: 'mySlides',
            children: [
              {
                tag: 'div',
                className: 'numbertext'
              },
              {
                tag: 'img',
                style: 'width: 100%'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            tag: 'a',
            className: 'prev',
            onclick: function(){plusSlides(-1)},
            innerHTML: '&#10094'
          },
          {
            tag: 'a',
            className: 'next',
            onclick: function(){plusSlides(1)},
            innerHTML: '&#10095'
          }
        ] 
      }
    ]
  });
}
function render(obj) {
  var el = document.createElement(obj.tag);
  if(obj.children){
    for(var i=0;i<obj.children.length;i++) {
      el.appendChild(render(obj.children[i]));
    }
  }
  delete el.tag;
  delete el.children;
  for(var key in obj){
    el[key] = obj[key];
  }
  return el;
}

function openModal() {
  document.body.appendChild(modal);
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.remove();
}

var slideIndex = 0;

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.column img');
  var captionText = modal.querySelector(".numbertext");
  var modalImg = modal.querySelector('img');
  n %= slides.length;
  modalImg.src = slides[n].src;
  captionText.innerHTML = n + 1 + ' / ' + slides.length;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(0)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>
```

***--- VERSION 3 ---***
To give an example for the new requirement down the comments, here is an example for two image categories, used one modal:

```js
var modal = initModal();

function initModal() {
  return render({
    tag: 'div',
    id: 'myModal',
    className: 'modal',
    children: [
      {
        tag: 'span',
        className: 'close cursor',
        onclick: closeModal,
        innerHTML: '&times;'
      },
      {
        tag: 'div',
        className: 'modal-content',
        children: [
          {
            tag: 'div',
            className: 'mySlides',
            children: [
              {
                tag: 'div',
                className: 'numbertext'
              },
              {
                tag: 'img',
                style: 'width: 100%'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            tag: 'a',
            className: 'prev',
            onclick: function(){plusSlides(-1)},
            innerHTML: '&#10094'
          },
          {
            tag: 'a',
            className: 'next',
            onclick: function(){plusSlides(1)},
            innerHTML: '&#10095'
          }
        ] 
      }
    ]
  });
}
function render(obj) {
  var el = document.createElement(obj.tag);
  if(obj.children){
    for(var i=0;i<obj.children.length;i++) {
      el.appendChild(render(obj.children[i]));
    }
  }
  delete el.tag;
  delete el.children;
  for(var key in obj){
    el[key] = obj[key];
  }
  return el;
}

function openModal() {
  document.body.appendChild(modal);
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.remove();
}

var slideIndex = 0;
var category = 'cat-1';

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n, cat) {
  category = cat;
  openModal();
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#'+category+' img');
  var captionText = modal.querySelector(".numbertext");
  var modalImg = modal.querySelector('img');
  n %= slides.length;
  modalImg.src = slides[n].src;
  captionText.innerHTML = n + 1 + ' / ' + slides.length;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row" id="cat-1">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(0, 'cat-1')" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1, 'cat-1')" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2, 'cat-1')" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3, 'cat-1')" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="cat-2">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1004/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(0, 'cat-2')" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1, 'cat-2')" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1006/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2, 'cat-2')" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3, 'cat-2')" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly, thank you so much! What if I wanted to create the model and delete it (When opening the photo close the modal)?

Comment: I don't want to Modal div to be seen in the console or my page elements... for example: `create.element('div')` and give it a class name Modal and append child to the body. and when closing the modal it'll remove the element from the page content

Comment: @Joseph I have add a new demo to create the structure on the fly. please take a look

Comment: It works very well here, but not on my website, I'll copy-paste and study it to figure it out... thank you so much!

Comment: I have a question please, what If I had 2 categories? the main problem will be is the Next/Prev buttons I guess! Is that right? because I tried to add `slideIndex1` + `plusSlides1` + `currentSlide1` and a new function `function showSlides1` to match the second category but it didn't work

Comment: please clarify again. What you are trying to archive now?

Comment: I have two `rows` each row contains 6 photos ( #Gallery1 and #Gallery2) I tried this method but it opens only one gallery, when I click on any image on the sec gallery it opens in full screen but when I press next or prev it shows the photos from gallery1

Comment: On the row `var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.column img');` it's select all the gallery images, to choose what to show. give a unique class for each category and select by that, then it should work fine

Comment: yeah I did that `var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#gallery1 img');` but what about the second one?

Comment: for the second one `var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#gallery2 img');`

Comment: Can't do that in the same function!

Comment: Why not? let the function receive the category as a parameter, the select `document.querySelectorAll('#"+category+' img')`

Comment: How? I mean which function!?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a 3-rd version, please take a look there

Comment: I have achieved everything I need, thank you so much Yousef! I appreciate that!